Equality of two time averages in a Markov chain
Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a Markov chain with irreducible transition matrix $P$ and finite state space $E$. Let $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of iid mean one exponential random variables independent of $X$. Fix $x\in E$. Note that by the ergodic theorem,
$$\pi(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb 1_{\{x\}}(X_i)\in[0,1]$$
is the fraction of time spent in $x$.
I would like to show that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb 1_{\{x\}}(X_i)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb 1_{\{x\}}(X_i)e_i.
\end{equation}
My thoughts on the problem
Note that this not simply a problem from analysis:
Knowing that (by the strong law of large numbers)
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}e_i=1
\end{equation}
is not enough. Indeed, fix a sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ in $E$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1_{\{x\}}(x_i)=\pi(x)$$
and set
$$e_i=\frac{1}{1-\pi(x)}1_{\{E\setminus x\}}(x_i).$$
Then $(2)$ is clearly satisfied, but
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb 1_{\{x\}}(X_i)e_i=0\neq \pi(x).$$
